How to simulate an enter key press in tmux command-prompt with the "-I" option?
Is it possible to include a enter character for tmux to use when using command-prompt's -I option?
I'd like it to operate like a key-press; but \n and \r don't really do the job.
The command argument would maybe include it in the string that I set the prompt with...
Or maybe it's better to just avoid it all together than just use run-shell, but then there won't be any command-prompt residue if I want to bring up the old command.
